# When does compact convergence imply convergence of integrals on the whole space?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ pointwise and also that the convergence is uniform on compact sets (here $f_n:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R})$). Then, clearly
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^N f_n(u) du = \int_0^N f(u) du $ for every fixed 
$N$ (The integrals are Reimann). Now, when can we say
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^\infty f_n(u) du = \int_0^\infty f(u) du$? (the integrals are improper Reimann integrals, assuming that all the improper integrals here exist)?

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry. Let $f_n(x)=\chi_{(n,n+1)}(x)$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function on $A$. Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function, and converges uniformly on every compact set. But $$\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx=1$$ but $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=0.$$

There are a few rather general conditions under which we can pass the limit through the integral. If the sequence $f_n(x)$ is positive and monotone for each $x$, we can do this (this is called the Lebesgue Monotone Convergence Theorem). Of course, if you have compact uniform convergence, your functions only have to be monotone outside of some compact set.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that this is in general not possible and therefore I have edited the question to "when"?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the edit. I, in turn, just edited the answer to include a condition when you can do what you suggest.

Comment: The example was nice anyway. I do not assume that the functions are Lebesgue Integrable on $[0,\infty)$.